# C# Generic Extension for async methods

Tags: c#, generics, asynchronous, telerik, extension-methods

I'm trying to create a generic extension method for Telerik's JustMock framework.

The framework offers a method with the following signature:
`IAssertable IFunc<T>.Returns(T value)`.

This way I can do the following:

```
var obj = Mock.Create<MyClass>();
obj.Arrange(o => o.GetTitle()).Returns("My Title");
```

In order to mock an async method, I would do this:

```
 var man = Mock.Create<SyncManager>();

 man.Arrange(manager => manager.SendPending(Arg.IsAny<TaskList>()))
       .Returns(Task.FromResult(default(Task)));
```

In order to avoid having to type `Returns(Task.FromResult(default(Task)))` everytime I mock an async method (that returns Task), I though I'd try writing an extension method called ReturnsTask:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IAssertable ReturnsTask<T>(this IFunc<T> func)
    {
        return func.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(T)));
    }
}
```

However, when I run this method I get the following message:

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type  
'Telerik.JustMock.Expectations.FuncExpectation`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]' to type
'Telerik.JustMock.Expectations.FuncExpectation`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]]'.
```

**EDIT**

Full stack trace

System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'Telerik.JustMock.Expectations.FuncExpectation`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]' to type 'Telerik.JustMock.Expectations.FuncExpectation`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Threading.Tasks.Task]]'.

```
at Telerik.JustMock.Helpers.MultipleReturnValueChainHelper.[](IAssertable )

at Telerik.JustMock.Helpers.MultipleReturnValueChainHelper.Returns(IAssertable assertable, TReturn value)

at Test.MyExtensions.ReturnsTask(IFunc`1 func) in SyncManagerTest.cs: line 115

at Test.SyncManagerTest.<TestSync>d__3.MoveNext() in SyncManagerTest.cs: line 57

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)

at NUnit.Core.AsyncSynchronizationContext.AsyncOperation.Invoke()

at NUnit.Core.AsyncSynchronizationContext.AsyncOperationQueue.InvokePendingOperations()

at NUnit.Core.AsyncSynchronizationContext.AsyncOperationQueue.InvokeAll()

at NUnit.Core.AsyncSynchronizationContext.WaitForPendingOperationsToComplete()

at NUnit.Core.NUnitAsyncTestMethod.RunVoidAsyncMethod(TestResult testResult)
```

Line 115

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IAssertable ReturnsTask<T>(this IFunc<T> func)
    {
        **return func.Returns(Task.FromResult(default(T)));**
    }
}
```

Line 57

```
        var man = Mock.Create<SyncManager>();
        var counter = 0;

        **man.Arrange(manager => manager.SendPending(Arg.IsAny<TaskList>()))**
            .DoInstead(() => counter++ )
            .ReturnsTask()
            .MustBeCalled();
```

Comment: In which line? Stack trace?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, I added the stack trace and some code snippets to the post.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on those lines, do you get the expected types for the involved objects? is **T** in line 115 **Task** or **Task<Task>**?

Comment: @PauloMorgado, If I set a breakpoint on line 115, T is of type Task. Weirdly, `default(T)` is null... not sure if that's relevant..

Comment: given that at **Task** is a reference type, it's default value is **null**.
But, if T is Task, then Task.FromResult(default()) returns **Task<Task>**.
**MustBeCalled** is expected to be applied to what?

Comment: `MustBeCalled()` is a member of the `IMustBeCalled` interface. And `Returns(T value)` returns an IAssertable. Now that you mention that, I don't see how you would be able to call `MustBeCalled()` on the return value of `Returns`... It does work though.

Comment: Why don't you try this:

`var v1 = man.Arrange(manager => manager.SendPending(Arg.IsAny<TaskList>()));
var v2 = v1.DoInstead(() => counter++ );
var v3 = v2.ReturnsTask()
var v4 = v3.MustBeCalled();`

and see the types of **v1**, **v2**, **v3** and **v4**.

Comment: v1 = `FuncExpectation<Task>`, v2 = `IFunc<Task>`, v3 = `IAssertable`. I can't declare v4 because `MustBeCalled()` returns void.

Comment: And if you run it, which one throws the exception now?

Comment: v3, inside the ReturnsTask, on line 115, same exception as before.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help because I don't have JustMock. Have you tried the Telerik forums?

Comment: I haven't, but that's a good tip, I'll try it. Thanks anyway.